# Parallel map operations?

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-collections

Does Scala provide a way to execute parallel map operations as part of the standard language?

For example, given:

```
scala> val a = List((1,2), (3,4), (3,6))
a: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (3,6))
```

I can do:

```
scala> a.map(tup => tup._1 + tup._2)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 7, 9)
```

However, to the best of my knowledge this maps the provided function over the list objects sequentially. Is there a built-in way to have the function applied to each element in a separate thread (or equivalent), and the results then gathered into a resulting list?

Comment: Don't use `List` for distributed (`par`) operations. You should use an `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: @senia - can you just elaborate shortly on why using a list is a bad idea in this case? I do not need the resulting list to be ordered in any way.

Comment: It's because of the way `par` method creates `parallel collection`.  For `Vector` (default `IndexedSeq` implementation), `Range` and `Array` it just wraps initial collection with lightweight wrapper. But for `List` it should create a completely new collection, it could lead to performance issue. See [Creating a Parallel Collection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html#creating_a_parallel_collection).

Comment: For the sake of precision in language, "parallel" and "distributed" really should not be conflated.

Comment: Right, fixing that. Also, thanks a lot for the clarification @senia

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you add `par` then you will get a parallel collection and operations on it will be processed in parallel. To convert back to a normal collection call a `toList`.

So your code would look like:

```
a.par.map(tup => tup._1 + tup._2).toList
```

Or a `.seq` to get a Sequential Collection (the *opposite* of a Parallel Collection).

```
a.par.map(tup => tup._1 + tup._2).seq
```

[Also, check the documentation.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html)

Answer (score 8):

`par` splits your list for processing over several threads. You can then regulate how the threading is done by modyfying the [`tasksupport`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq) member of the resultant `ParSeq`.