# Scala Future or other way to execute Java void methods in parallel

Tags: scala, future

I have the following piece of code:

```
stringList map copyURLToFile // List[String]

def copyURLToFile(symbol: String) = {
  val url = new URL(base.replace("XXX", symbol))
  val file = new File(prefix + symbol + ".csv")
  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file)
}
```

How do I make copyURLToFile execute in parallel?

Scala Futures need a return type, but if I make copyURLToFile of type Future[Unit], what and how do I return from the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallel map operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092855/parallel-map-operations)

Comment: You could just add `future` between `=` and `{`like this: `def copyURLToFile(symbol: String) = future{`

Comment: I tried having function body in Future {} and recursively going through the list, but it didn't work. Recursion worked but calls to org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile didn't (no files were created).  I guess the problem was that Java method returns void.

Comment: Actually the issue was probably that I was executing that as a standalone program whose main thread terminated before worker threads could execute as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565475/possible-bug-in-scala-2-10-futures-do-not-run?rq=1

Comment: Void is not a problem per se, the problem is that your main thread does not access the result, thus it doesn't wait for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a very easy way to parallelize this, then just map over the list using [the parallel collections library](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html).

```
stringList.par.map(copyURLToFile).toList
```

Comment: Works great. Much faster now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something, how are you going to know which files where downloaded?

Change your code to be:

```
def copyURLToFile(symbol: String): (String,String) = {
  val url = new URL(base.replace("XXX", symbol))
  val file = new File(prefix + symbol + ".csv")
  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file)
  return (symbol, file)
}
```

And then the resulting collection will contain the symbols an the paths to the file where they were downloaded.

Comment: The bigger problem is that the code does not wait for the download to complete, because it does not try to access the results.